# Slight dent in motorcycle oil filter: bad for flow?

Tags: motorcycle, oil, oil-filter

I replaced my motorcycles oil filter the other day and accidentally dented the outside casing of the new one putting it on.

I know its probably nothing, but would this impact the flow of oil through the filter?

Comment: Could you add some description -- or even a photo -- of the extent and location of the dent?

Answer (score 2):

In all probability it would be okay to use an oil filter with a minor dent in it,  but why take an unnecessary risk? For just a few dollars you can fit a replacement oil filter where the integrity of the part is assured.

Comment: Yeah it probably is ok. But I stupidly did the damage after I put in the new oil and was putting on the protective cap over the filter (ironic I know) so I would have to replace the oil again to replace the filter. Haha you mean Griffith on the Gold Coast? My brother went there too

Comment: Yes, Griffith. He stayed in a place called Southport.(I hope I've spelt that right:-))